# Animate cycle through list items

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-animate, ticker

I have a list of words contained within a `<div>`, the `<div>` overflow is set to hidden so only one list-item is displayed at a time. I want each list item to slide up one by one but without using the [`.slideUp()`](https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) function. I want it to look like as one moves off at the top, the other emerges from the bottom. I also want the list items to loop round.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="band_ticker">
        <ul id="slide">
            <li><h2 class="band">BAND</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="band">PARTY BAND</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="band">COPORATE EVENTS</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="band">WEDDINGS</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="band">FUNCTION BAND</h2></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Can I get some help writing the jQuery code to loop through these by animating each item upwards?

Comment: Here at stack overflow we do not write code for you. We will help you find some plugins though so can get started. Then after you have some code written and have problems, we have help with those specifics. This question is too vague and is asking us to write code for you.

Comment: I have same problem with some extra functionality i want to scroll top and bottom side with on click function is there any way. It should be more helpful if you can provide jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is some code, originally from the workshop.rs:

JS:

```
function tick(){
    $('#ticker li:first').animate({'opacity':0}, 200, function () {
    $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).css('opacity', 1); });
}
setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 4000);
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="ticker">
    <li>
        <a href="http://workshop.rs/2009/12/jqbargraph-jquery-graph-plugin/">jqBarGraph</a> is jQuery plugin that gives you freedom to easily display your data as graphs. There are three types of graphs: simple, multi and stacked.
    </li>
    <li>
        Learn how to create <a href="http://workshop.rs/2010/07/create-image-gallery-in-4-lines-of-jquery/">image gallery in 4 lines of Jquery</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://workshop.rs/2009/12/image-gallery-with-fancy-transitions-effects">jqFancyTransitions</a> is easy-to-use jQuery plugin for displaying your photos as slideshow with fancy transition effects.
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://workshop.rs/2010/02/moobargraph-ajax-graph-for-mootools/">mooBarGraph</a> is AJAX graph plugin for MooTools which support two types of graphs, simple bar and stacked bar graph.
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was after. Thanks for the help

Comment: I have same problem with some extra functionality i want to scroll top and bottom side with on click function is there any way. It should be more helpful if you can provide jsfiddle example.

Comment: @Anup, you are best off asking a new question instead of commenting on an old one. Reference back to this question to help those who will answer know where you are coming from.

Comment: It will really help to paste some code (I'm assuming from the title of the link that it really is 4 lines) In case the link is no longer valid.

Comment: @UpHelix your links are dead.